# How can a value be stored before the jvm exits?

Tags: java, serialization

When my program exits I want to store an integer value that is loaded again when theh program starts.

Is serialization an option?

Comment: upvote ^this^ comment because it describes what i am feeling exactly!

Comment: You have to use serialization, an SQL database or a configuration file (or anything equivalent to the above), when the program exits its memory ceases to exist as far as you should be concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to look into serialization.

- Serialization helps you write the state of the object in a file
- Use deserialization when you want to read the state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You have following options:

1. Serialize and store the value in a file and read it when you restart the application.
2. Store it in DB before closing app and reload when restarting the app.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is definitely an option. In the init of your class having the variable, you have to load the value from somewhere (server, file, etc.). Since its that simple (one int) I suggest to load it from the file or [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Take a look at this `Properties` example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a variable to retain its value between program executions. Save it to a file at program exit and attempt to read it from the same file at program startup (or initialize it to a default value if the file isn't there).

Answer (score 0):

You could store it to a .txt file and have it read it back in and set the variable.